# How to add multiple yubikey PIV authentication keys to ssh-agent with ssh-add?

Tags: ssh, pkcs#11, yubikey

I have to ssh through a jump host to a remote server, both the jumpbox and the remote server have their own ssh keys stored on yubikeys.

When I have tried using ssh-agent with ssh-add to add the keys it only prompted me for one yubikey pin (even when both were plugged in), furthermore I have no way of knowing which key it was loading or which pin to use - although ssh-add seems to figure out which card to add based on which PIN I enter:

```
$  ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
Enter passphrase for PKCS#11: <PIN #1>
Card added: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

and when trying to add the other key, it fails:

```
$ ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
Enter passphrase for PKCS#11: <PIN #2>
Could not add card "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so": agent refused operation
```

trying with libykcs11 also fails when trying to add the second card (after successfully loading the first):

```
$ ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libykcs11.so
Enter passphrase for PKCS#11: <PIN #2>
Could not add card "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libykcs11.so": agent refused operation
```

Using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

According to a detailed report:

https://www.spinics.net/lists/openssh-unix-dev/msg06440.html

it seems each "provider" or pkcs11 library, can only be added once.